# How to change the default limit of maxOccurs in Spring-WS version 2.4.4 or higher?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, xsd, spring-ws

After updating Spring Boot 1.5.18 to a higher version I got the following error:

*Not supported: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD*

After some investigation I found that this problem starts with Spring-XML 2.4.4.

I resolved this with the help of https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1410603, but after that I got the following error:

*org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidationException: Could not create Schema: Current configuration of the parser doesn't allow a maxOccurs attribute value to be set greater than the value 5.000*

How do I change the parser to accept higher maxOccurs values than 5000 in my XSD with Spring-XML version 2.4.4 or higher?

I tried using System.setProperty("jdk.xml.maxOccurLimit", "XXXXX") and tried setting attributes or properties as in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/using.html

This is the bean that is producing the exception:

```java
@Bean
public PayloadValidatingEndpointInterceptor payloadValidatingEndpointInterceptor() {
    PayloadValidatingEndpointInterceptor payloadValidatingEndpointInterceptor = new PayloadValidatingEndpointInterceptor();
    payloadValidatingEndpointInterceptor.setValidateRequest(true);
    payloadValidatingEndpointInterceptor.setValidateResponse(true);
    payloadValidatingEndpointInterceptor.setXsdSchema(schema());
    return payloadValidatingEndpointInterceptor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting the system property in the wrong location. Because we are using JBoss I had to add a JbossSystemPropertySpec with name="jdk.xml.maxOccurLimit" to the configuration of the xldeploy-maven-plugin in our pom.